# How to check if the item satisfies all of the conditions from the conditions array?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, filtering

I want to make a function that filters the items by checking if they satisfy all of the conditions provided. The function receives 2 parameters: (data, include):

```
data: [
    { user: "mike@mail.com", rating: 20, disabled: false },
    { user: "greg@mail.com", rating: 14, disabled: false },
    { user: "john@mail.com", rating: 25, disabled: true }
  ]


include: [{ disabled: false }, { rating: 20 }]
```

With the data above, for example, the function should return the array with only one entry:

```
[{ user: "mike@mail.com", rating: 20, disabled: false }]
```

Because that entry has both *disabled: false* and *rating: 20*.

So my function is:

```
const filterInclude = (data, include) => {
  const result = [];

  data.forEach((item) => {
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(item)) {
      include.forEach((cond) => {
        if (cond.hasOwnProperty(key) && cond[key] === value) {
          result.push(item);
        }
      });
    }
  });

  return result;
};
```

It works correctly when the include array has only 1 item, for example:

```
include: [{ disabled: false }]
```

However, when there are multiple conditions, it's not working correctly because it pushes the item to the result if it satisfies at least 1 condition.

How to improve this function to make it work correctly and push the item to the result only when it satisfies all of the conditions?

Comment: Why reinvent Array.filter() ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: you're right, filter is better. But the problem is how to set the condition

Answer (score 0):

Just use the filter function as follows:

```
 const filterInclude = ({data, disabled, rating })=> data.filter((el) => el.disabled === disabled && el.rating === rating )
```

Use it as follows:

```
const data= [
    { user: "mike@mail.com", rating: 20, disabled: false },
    { user: "greg@mail.com", rating: 14, disabled: false },
    { user: "john@mail.com", rating: 25, disabled: true }
  ];

console.log(filterInclude({data, disabled: false, rating: 20}))
```

Comment: thank you. However, this function should be versatile. The condition array can have many different properties, for example [{isYoung: true},{age: 20},{name: 'John'}]. And the function doesn't know in advance what props will come but it should work with any conditions of any quantity

Answer (score 0):

So I accomplished what the task requires. Here is the improved code in case somebody needs something similar in the future:

```
const checkInclude = (item, include) => {
  let numOfSatisfied = 0;

  conditions: for (let cond of include) {
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(item)) {
      if (cond.hasOwnProperty(key) && cond[key] === value) {
        numOfSatisfied++;
        continue conditions;
      }
    }
  }

  return numOfSatisfied === include.length ? true : false;
};

const filterInclude = (data, include) => {
  const result = data.filter((item) => checkInclude(item, include));

  return result;
};
```

Comment: nice one, instead of this return numOfSatisfied === include.length ? true : false;   just do this instead  return numOfSatisfied === include.length

Answer (score 0):

hope i am not late, just kidding.

```
let response  = data.filter(each=>{
    let count =  include.reduce((a,item)=>{
      const [keys,value] = Object.entries(item)[0]
      if (each[keys] ===value) a++
       return a
     },0)
     return count == include.length
})

console.log(response)
```